# Lipschitz Function Properties

Tags: calculus

I am stuck on how to show this works for all functions. I had been working on showing it for a few examples, but I get stuck with the absolute of the derivative idea. I think if I can get through that idea, I may be able to show it for all functions.

[image]

Comment: Use mean value theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $|f'(x)|\leq M$ for some $M$ greater than zero.

Pick $x,y\in [a,b]$.Let´s say $x\leq y$ Using Lagrange's theorem, we get

$f(x)-f(y)=f'(t)(x-y)$

for some $t\in (x,y)$.Taking absolute value and using the hypothesis about $f'$, we get

$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M |x-y|$.